# Android, java, Xml Parsin Using Dom

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

How can I parse this tag using the DOM?

`<gd:where startTime="Jan 4 2012" endTime="Jan 5 2012"/>`

I wants the `startTime` and `endTime` from this tag.

Comment: what do you have atm? you can even use regular expression to do this

Comment: No I am not able to parse gd:when

Comment: I am trying to parse xml from this url google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/… It returns me an xml and I am parsing it using Dom I can pick title from this xml very easily. But When I try to parse <gd:when> tag It is not working

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
getAttributeValue(null,"startTime")
```

Comment: I am trying to parse xml from this url

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic

It returns me an xml and I am parsing it using Dom
I can pick title from this xml very easily.

But When I try to parse <gd:when> tag It is not working

Comment: Yes Here is what i am doing

URL url = new URL(
           "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Comment: NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("gd:when");

But when I check its length its zero

Comment: listen i have used XmlPullParser. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html . you will find lot of xample about it by searching on google.

Comment: NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
I tried to get title and its working perfect..

Answer (score 0):

Writing an xml parser is very instructive, but if you are having troubles with the namespaces. I would recommend using an existent xml parsing library.

If you want to know, search for *parsing xml elements with namespaces*

[simplexml](http://simple.sourceforge.net) and [xpath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) should both work fine.